# Problems capturing value into string

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf, md5

I am new to c and I know I am doing something wrong, but really could use some help here.

I am attempting to take a string and get an MD5 checksum hash of it.  I have working codes that calculate the MD5 very nicely (below). They work very well and I have no issues with them.  My problem is capturing the output of this function into a string.  I know it is simple, but I am not sure what I am screwing up:

```
// MD5 Hash query_string for return checksum
int i;
unsigned char result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
unsigned char returnCheck;

MD5(query_string, strlen(query_string), result);

// output
for(i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
    printf("MD return   = %02x\n", result[i]);
    returnCheck += result[i];
    printf("returnCheck = %02x\n",returnCheck);
    }
```

As you can see I am trying to take the output of result[i] and concatenate it into a single string (returnCheck).  The problem is I am not getting the correct values into returnCheck.  See output below:

```
MD return   = 6b
returnCheck = 6b
MD return   = 84
returnCheck = ef
MD return   = 12
returnCheck = 01
MD return   = a6
returnCheck = a7
MD return   = a9
returnCheck = 50
MD return   = 96
returnCheck = e6
MD return   = 98
returnCheck = 7e
MD return   = 52
returnCheck = d0
MD return   = 3b
returnCheck = 0b
MD return   = d6
returnCheck = e1
MD return   = 32
returnCheck = 13
MD return   = 77
returnCheck = 8a
MD return   = 0c
returnCheck = 96
MD return   = b4
returnCheck = 4a
MD return   = 3d
returnCheck = 87
MD return   = 4f
returnCheck = d6
```

The MD5 I should be getting in this example is '6b8412a6a99698523bd632770cb43d4f' which the MD return is showing correctly, but not returnCheck.  The goal is at the end of this function to have a single string named 'returnCheck' with the value of '6b8412a6a99698523bd632770cb43d4f'.

Please help!

-- I also tried --

```
// MD5 Hash query_string for return checksum
int i;
unsigned char result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
char returnCheck[32] = "";

MD5(query_string, strlen(query_string), result);

// output
for(i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
    printf("MD return   = %02x\n", result[i]);
    returnCheck[i] = result[i];
    printf("returnCheck = %x\n",returnCheck);
    }
```

Comment: `returnCheck` is a single character, not a string.  The `+=` operation is not concatenation; it is arithmetic.  So, you need an array of characters and you need to worry about null termination.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried that (see above for code changes) still does not work?  What am I screwing up?

Comment: @StevenCarlson In your edited version you are not using the index `[i]` when you are printing out the values of `returnCheck`.

Comment: @BrianRogers right, I want to see all the characters in the array/string not just the ones I just entered.  I need to be able to get the full string's value which should be the full 32 bits once the for loop is finished.

Comment: Note that the result string will be 33 bytes (not 32 bits).  There will be 32 hex digits plus a trailing null byte indicating the end of the string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you are right, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sprintf each result[i] to an intermediate array and strcat that to returnCheck

```
int i;
unsigned char result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
char returnCheck[34] = "";
char hex[3] = "";

MD5(query_string, strlen(query_string), result);

// output
for(i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
{
    sprintf(hex, "%02x", result[i]);
    strcat ( returnCheck, hex);
}
printf ( "%s\n", returnCheck);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sprintf()` or `snprintf()` incrementally is OK, but there's no need for an intermediate buffer:

```
unsigned char result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
char returnCheck[2 * MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH + 1] = "";
size_t offset = 0;

MD5(query_string, strlen(query_string), result);

for (int i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    offset += sprintf(&returnCheck[offset], "%02x", result[i]);
assert(offset < sizeof(returnCheck));
printf("%s\n", returnCheck);
```

Or, using `snprintf()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    offset += snprintf(&returnCheck[offset], sizeof(returnCheck) - 2 * i, "%02x", result[i]);
```

Often, it is better to use `snprintf()`.  Here, you know that the sizes are OK so there's no real benefit to it.

If this is in the body of a function, don't attempt to return `returnCheck`.

This is written using C99; if your compiler doesn't like the `for (int i = 0; …)` notation, either set it so it does accept C99 or C11, or get a better compiler, or declare `int i` outside the loops at the start of a block and omit the `int` in the `for` loop.